# Как работает конкретная локальная сеть с точки зрения OSI?

Tags: сеть, роутер, osi

Вот пытаюсь построить у себя в голове картину как работает моя локалка по OSI.

Моя локалка — два компа по Ethernet'у подключены к роутеру.

И так. Роутер это несколько устройств в одном (следовательно, роутер выполняет функции устройств, которые находятся на нескольких уровнях OSI).

И соответственно есть роутеры более "умные" и более "глупые" — по количеству устройств соединенных в нем (функций).

Сейчас у меня в голове складывается такая картина, что в роутере стоит:

1. регенератор он же повторитель
2. сетевой концетратор (он же хаб), но не всего его функции включены
3. сетевой комутатор (он же свич), который может работать как хаб
4. маршрутизатор (собственно, сам роутер)

И по OSI выходит так:

1. На Физическом уровне работает повторитель и хаб. Повторитель восстанавливает сигнал после определенной степени потерь, хаб позволяет подключить к роутеру несколько устройств.
2. На Канальном уровне работает свич. На этом уровне появляется MAC-адрес. И у свича каждому разъему соответствует MAC-адрес подключенного сетевого устройства. Он шлет входящие пакеты на нужный MAC. Т.е. свич это как бы "продвинутый" хаб.
   И правильней будет сказать, что в роутере хаба нету, а есть свич, который может работать как хаб.
   Так же на этом уровне работает ARP/RARP протоколы. ARP работает для входных пакетов (IP-адресу в соответствие разьем с MAC-адресом). А RARP работает для выходных пакетов.
3. На Сетевом уровне работает маршрутизатор. На этом уровне появляется IP-адрес. У маршрутизатора есть таблица маршрутов (которая периодически обновляется) и он шлет по нужному IP адресу пакет.

А вот какое физическое устройство идет на Транспортном уровне?

И у меня складывается впечатление что модель OSI это как бы среднестатистическая модель. При практической реализации сети идет то или иное отклонение в ту или иную сторону от OSI. Нет?

Comment: P.S. Чет кажется вопрос заминусуют.

Comment: Вспомнил, что на Транспортном уровне появляется понятие "порт" (программный порт), как минимум для того, что бы решать задачу мультиплексирования пакетов — например, когда к роутеру подключены два ПК, оба шлют запрос к гуглу, у двух пакетов стоит IP-шник роутера и роутеру нужно знать какой пакет-ответ какому компу из локалки доставить.

Получается, что роутер захватывает и транспортный уровень.

Comment: "А вот какое физическое устройство идет на Транспортном уровне?"-никакое. Модуль ОС, реализующий соответствующий протокол.

Comment: @VadimTagil, не уверен. У меня есть аргументы против :).
(в один комментарий все не влезло)

1)
На Транспортном уровне решается проблема мультиплексирования.
Я выше писал пример, извиняюсь за повторение. Пусть к роутеру подключены два компьютера и оба посылают пакеты на гугл. При выходе из роутера обеим пакетам присваивается IP-адрес роутера. И этот адрес "путешествует" по всему интернету, при этом изменяясь по определенным алгоритмам (у меня в голове такая картина) и затем гугл шлет мне ответы — два пакета, которые доходят до моего роутера, и имеют IP-адрес роутера.

Comment: 2)И роутер должен понять какому из двух компьютеров, подключенным, к нему какой из двух пакетов слать.
Так вот. Если проблема мультиплексирования решается на уровне ОС, то это значит, что оба компьютера, подключенные к роутеру должны получить оба пакета. А так как в роутере стоит свич, то он не должен допустить такого (в зависимости от настроек), что бы одному компьютеру пришел пакет-ответ для другого компьютера (т.к. в свиче к каждому входу привязан MAC адрес).

Comment: 3)Следовательно, с учетом вышесказанного, можно сделать вывод что роутер работает и на транспортном уровне, решая, по крайней мере проблему мультиплексирования (внутри самого себя — т.е. через свой сетевой процессор/контроллер).

Могу предположить, что другая часть транспортного уровня реализуется драйвером роутера уже на уровне ОС. Или не драйвером роутера, а другим ПО, но все-равно на уровне ОС.

Comment: если используется NAT то да, в каком-то смысле он является устройством транспортного уровня. Мой ответ относился к "Моя локалка — два компа по Ethernet'у подключены к роутеру.", а не к взаимодействию с внешним миром

Comment: Функции NAT больше относятся к фаерволу, чем к роутингу, т.е. это дополнительная обработка пакетов, а то что там порты (tcp/udp) затронуты - так это не во всех видах NAT'a, да и то - больше похоже на 
 побочный эффект от костыля :) Всё просто - 1 и 2 уровень реализованы блоком коммутации (свитч), а 3 (с некоторыми возможностями более высоких уровней) - это уже роутер.